# Show that a norm defines a topology in a vector $\mathbb K$-space $V$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

A metric field is a pair $(K, | |)$, where $K$ is a field and $| |$ is an absolute value in K.
An absolute value in K is any function $||:K\rightarrow R$ , where R is an Archimedean ordered field, which fulfills the following properties:

a) $| x | ≥ 0$ and the only element of $K$ that satisfies $| x | = 0$ is $x = 0$.

b) $| x + y | ≤ | x | + |y|$

c) $| xy | = | x || y |$

Considering $\mathbb K$ as a metric field.
If $V$ is any $\mathbb K$-vector space of finite dimension $n$, there exists an isomorphism
$f: V  →\mathbb K^n$.We can consider the $V$ topology formed by the sets $F^{−1}[G]$, where $G$ is open in $\mathbb K^n$ for the Euclidean topology.

Given the norm $||$ $||:V → \mathbb R$ given by $||v||= ||f (v) ||$.

Then Show that this norm induces the above topology in $V$.

Comment: When you give that norm to $V$, $f$ becomes an isometric isomorphism. Thus $V$ and $\mathbb{K}^n$ are identical as normed spaces. $f$ is easily shown to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: What are the consequences of $V$ and $\mathbb K^n$ being identical as normed spaces?

Comment: There are no consequences, other than emphasizing that since the normed spaces are identical through $f$, it is plausible that $f$ is a homeomorphism. We have $\lVert v_n - v \rVert \to 0 \iff \lVert f(v_n) - f(v) \rVert \to 0$, so $f$ is indeed a homeomorphism. This implies that $U$ is open in $V$ if and only if $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{K}^n$.

Comment: $G$ is Open in $V⟺\land x\in G\exists \epsilon>0$ and $\{y\in V{\Large |} ||x-y||<\epsilon\}\subset G$⟺$\land f(x)\in f[G]\exists \epsilon>0$ and $\{f(y)\in f[V]{\Large |} ||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon\}\subset G⟺f[G]$ is open in $\mathbb {K}^n$ .Then $f$ is a homeomophism. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you meant $\subset f[G]$ in the second line.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help.